# Cannot Upgrade Google Cloud SQL to Second Generation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I cannot upgrade the First generation Google Cloud Instance to Second generation instance using MySQL Second Generation upgrade wizard in console.
During the check configuration screen, I get **Tables that use the MEMORY storage engine found** error due to which I cannot proceed further as shown in screenshot
 [image: Error in Console]
According to documentation at [Upgrading a First Generation instance to Second Generation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-2nd-gen), I have verified using the query mentioned in documentation.

[image: Documentation]

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, table_type
   FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE engine = 'MEMORY' AND
   table_schema NOT IN
   ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema');
```

but found **no tables** using a MEMORY storage engine as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the error and proceeded with upgrade. I had a to remove a table from the performance_schema database that did not use the PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA storage engine before starting the upgrade process. Seems Google Cloud console threw in an **irrelevant error**!